# Why does my email software turn the text "tel:" into a link?

Tags: microsoft-outlook-2007

I'm using outlook 2007, and have noticed that when I receive emails from a certain person, the first part of the telephone number is treated as a link. But of course, it doesn't work when you click it.

[image]

It's something to do with the text "tel"- it doesn't do it for anything else. But I don't understand what this feature is for. Is there a way to turn it off?

Comment: Skype installed on this system?

Comment: Nope, it's not.

Comment: Are you viewing messages as HTML?

Comment: @Dave M: Yes, I am.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`tel` is a valid URI scheme](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3966); `tel:` works in the same way `http:` does.

Microsoft Office (including Word and Outlook) will automatically change `tel:something` into a link. You can disable it following [these](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/msoffice/how-to-disable-automatic-hyperlinking/276) instructions (I'll add them below, too). However, **this link is inserted by the sender**. Your client is merely displaying that link as the sender intended. **You'll have to contact the sender and get them to stop**, which can mean turning off automatic hyperlinks if using Outlook. Of course, the easy (and recommended) way is to just remove the hyperlinks before sending.

If it really bugs you and the sender can't or won't change it, you can disable HTML messages in Outlook. That's a rather drastic action, though. It might also be possible to set up a spam filter to strip links from this sender. That will likely remove all hyperlinks, not just `tel:` ones.

#### Instructions to disable automatic hyperlinking

**Note: the easy way is to just remove the hyperlinks before sending.**
(Screenshots from Word 2010, but should work the same way in Outlook)

Basically, go to autocorrect options, autoformat as you type, and uncheck the hyperlinks option. **Warning: this will also turn off automatic `http:` hyperlinking.**

[image: Getting into Word options]
[image: Turning off the option]

Answer (score 0):

Its an html tag for putting a linkable phone number in websites.  http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/input/tel

i guess you'll have to add a line to the html before sending.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3736807/remove-styling-of-telephone-numbers